# Nested complex query to MongoDB with Python

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document in my MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a672fe5c9afd19e04d011ca"),
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Smith",
            "age" : 10,
            "spouse" : "Lopez"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Davis",
            "age" : 10,
            "spouse" : "Peter"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Clark",
            "age" : 10
        }
    ],
    "header" : {
        "sourece" : "http://www.some.com/api/json/data?department=security&gender=female",
        "fetch_time" : "2018-01-23T09:35:51"
    }
}
```

Now I want to:

1. Get all the data under "data" node.
2. Get all the people who have
   "spouse" node.

The following code doesn't work:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['test']
coll = db['test_2']

print('All content:')
for item in coll.find():
    pprint(item)

print('-'*20)
print("Content under 'data':")
for item in coll.find({"data": "$all"}):
    pprint(item)

for item in coll.find({"data": []}):
    pprint(item)

for item in coll.find({"data": ["$all"]}):
    pprint(item)

print('-'*20)
print("People who have 'spouse':")
for item in coll.find({"data": [{"spouse":"$all"}]}):
    pprint(item)
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
All content:
{u'_id': ObjectId('5a672fe5c9afd19e04d011ca'),
 u'data': [{u'age': 10, u'name': u'Smith', u'spouse': u'Lopez'},
           {u'age': 10, u'name': u'Davis', u'spouse': u'Peter'},
           {u'age': 10, u'name': u'Clark'}],
 u'header': {u'fetch_time': u'2018-01-23T09:35:51',
             u'sourece': u'http://www.some.com/api/json/data?department=security&gender=female'}}
--------------------
Content under 'data':
--------------------
People who have 'spouse':
```

I can get all the content from my MongoDB, which means the data is there in the database. But when I run the subsequent code, nothing was printed. I tried different ways but none of them work.

Moreover, is there any document like, say Oracle SQL reference.pdf stating the query statement grammar with strict structure specification so I can build any query statement based on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to get all data.

First part ( Regular Query )  - Read [`here`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) 
 - Use projection to output all data fields with no query filter.

Something like `coll.find({},{"data": 1})`.

Second part ( Aggregate Query ) - Read [`here`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) - Use [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to contain the documents where "data" have atleast have one array element where it has spouse field followed by [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) expression to check for missing field to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) matching array elements.

Something like

```
col.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"data.spouse":{"$exists":true}}},
  {"$project":{
    "data":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$data",
        "as":"result",
        "cond":{"$ne":[{"$type":"$$result.spouse"},"missing"]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Also not [`query operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) are different from [`aggregation comparison operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/).

Comment: This answer doesn't work, it returns:

assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$type'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed
....
Error: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$type'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed :
...

Comment: Thank you, your answer works with MongoDB 3.6, it exactly returned what I want.